# two different gpus in single computer/server

Tags: nvidia, gpu, dual-graphics

i am building a computer from scraps.

I have NVIDIA P1000 as GPU with output and just got my hands on NVIDIA Tesla T4

I am asking if i can use both GPUs and if there will be no issues regarding drivers and or resource usage.

Comment: Use both for what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.